# How best to interact with the candidates in a moderator election?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

I'm participating in the [ongoing election](https://ai.stackexchange.com/election), and, similar to one of the candidates, I have concerns about the statements made by some of the candidates.

Is there a way to reach out to the candidates and ask them questions?

My concern with the other candidates is *not* about who they are -- I know little about them -- but rather about questions they haven't answered:

1. Do you know what you are getting into? There's a lot of work involved in being a moderator.  I appreciate that some candidates are taking the philosophy, "good moderators do as little as possible," but do they know how much work it takes to do this?
2. What is your philosophy of moderation?  How do you deal with difficult moderation cases? I appreciate that some of the candidates desire to salvage what can be. How do they plan to deal with what cannot be salvaged?

I believe there are other questions I would ask if I could pose questions to the candidates either privately or publicly.

I'm a busy father and professional and unlikely to get too involved in this election.  But at a minimum level of engagement, how can I constructively help willing candidates improve their plans for moderation?

---

Also, how many moderators total will be selected in this election?  I read through the election page and feel that there's lots I still don't know about this election.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Often in elections, there's a questionnaire compiled by the community full of similar questions to the ones you've posted that candidates are encouraged to answer. Since this is technically a pro-tem election, that didn't happen this time.

During the "nomination" phase of the election, you can leave comments on the nominations. Once voting has opened, that's no longer an option, unfortunately.

I personally can be found in [The Singularity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43371/the-singularity), which is the main chat room for Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange, and am willing to answer questions posed there.

---

As for how many moderators are being elected, on the top right of the /election page it says this:

> candidates 6 | positions 1

There are six candidates running; one will be selected to be added to the moderator team.

Comment: Also, since I'm already a diamond moderator on different sites, I can superping any of the candidates in the chat room to give them a notification. if you'd like to pose questions to one of the other candidates, I might be able to summon them into that chat room.

Comment: Now that I see there is only one open position, I don't feel a need to contact any of the candidates. Thank you for your offer of help!

Comment: I would like to ask Rob how he plans to become familiar with the scope of this site if he is elected.  That is, what he already knows about what is [on](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and off topic and how committed he is to adjusting to the community's norms where he might disagree.

Comment: @JosiahYoder - Rob actually has me blocked on chat, I believe, so I'm not sure I'll be able to summon them, unfortunately.

Comment: That is unfortunate.

Comment: Has Rob requested neutral pronouns? I've seen a couple of folks using them.

Answer (score 0):

During the nomination phase, you could interact with the candidates. Unfortunately, I was the only one to do so, i.e. I was the only one to ask clarification questions, and I asked clarification questions to all of them (but Mithical, which I interacted with in our chat room and I knew them a little bit since I was once a mod too). So, it seems that almost nobody is interested in selecting the right person for this mod role...

I wish people could still see the comments, but, anyway, 2 people didn't really address my concerns at all (most of them are about their activity and contributions to the site, which were lacking or poor). I will write here their names because I think it's important for the community to choose the best candidate: quintumnia and Simbarashe Timothy Motsi. The other candidates tried, to some extent, to address my concerns, but I was not fully satisfied with their answers...

Personally, I think most nominations/candidates are not suitable for the role because, actually, all of them have been inactive for many years or never contributed to the site at all in any way, and only became active to nominate themselves (can you believe this? your judgement here!!!) and only some of them have showed to have some knowledge of AI and only 1-2 know how SE really works and seem to have an idea of what it means to be a mod.

Comment: Since there is only one open position, this is less of a concern.  It's deciding between those 1-2 who know how SE works that I'm thinking through....

I think it's OK to un-name the two candidates you name as I feel they are unlikely to be elected anyway.

Comment: @JosiahYoder I think that's a mistake. Selecting a mod only based on their knowledge of SE and how it works is a mistake. Mods on specific sites, especially one like ours (which falls under the "science" category), should have some knowledge of AI to be elected. I discussed this with Mithical on the chat. You can go there and read, if you want. But I will let the community decide what they think is the best!

Comment: What chat? I've got 2k on SO proper, but still feel like a newcomer to the whole network!

Comment: @JosiahYoder You're already there: [The Singularity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43371/the-singularity) ;)

Comment: I think none of the candidates have enough experience on this site to become a diamond moderator. I would like to vote for Ron (Re-open nominations). I didn't get the notification that an election was going on for some reason. Maybe SE didn't want me to participate.